# Get min/max values of a javascript array for array propriety

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the min/max values of a multidimensional javascript array dependant on 2 fields.

This is timeseries data from an IoT device, it sends me data in this format:

timestamp, device id, value1, value2, value3, etc, etc

I want to write a function to get the min/max value of each device for a particular value

I have a array like this

```
[
    [
        1577912341,
        "ITEM1",
        131.98840369
    ],
    [
        1577998742,
        "ITEM2",
        127.27418424
    ],
    [
        1578085141,
        "ITEM2",
        133.67909395
    ],
    [
        1578171541,
        "ITEM1",
        134.82513897
    ]
]
```

How can I get min/max value of each unique item in field 1 using the value in field 3 ?
For example I want to know the max value of the field 3 for (ITEM1), in this example that would be "134.82513897"

min value of field 2 (ITEM1)is 131.98840369
max value of field 2 (ITEM1)is 134.82513897

min value of field 2 (ITEM2)is 127.27418424
max value of field 2 (ITEM2)is 133.67909395

Comment: Is your IoT device somehow streaming this data at you, and you want to return a stream of min/max values at given times? Or does your IoT device give you the full set at once and you want to return the min/max of the data provided?

Comment: Both, I can get full dataset or get it in realtime (and populate an array with it), I would like to know the min/max of the available data up until that moment. I guess the method would be the same, it's basically an static array for min/max function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can get you started.

```js
const data = [
    [
        1577912341,
        "ITEM1",
        131.98840369
    ],
    [
        1577998742,
        "ITEM2",
        127.27418424
    ],
    [
        1578085141,
        "ITEM2",
        133.67909395
    ],
    [
        1578171541,
        "ITEM1",
        134.82513897
    ]
];
const items = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[1]))];
console.log(items);

const results = items.map(item => {
  const subset = data.filter(d => d[1] === item).map(d => d[2]);
  return {
    item: item,
    min: Math.min(...subset),
    max: Math.max(...subset)
  };
});
console.log(results);
```